# Can't display elements from the same variable php

Tags: php, json

I am working for a newspaper on my city, we hire a 3rd party company to build an app for us, and they are asking for jsons about our database, I really hate jsons always have hard time with them.

The problem I have is simple and complicated for me at least, I need to display only the elements with variable 7 on the column `entry_blog_id` which belong to table `mt_entry` the path would be `mt_entry.entry_blog_id`. The problem is when I declare `entry_blog_id = 7`, the code doesn't work, but if I delete that variable all the code works fine but choose all blogs id.

Here's is my full code, I need some help please (I know my English is horrible sorry about that)

```
if(isset($_GET['seccion']))
{
    $SQL = "SELECT entry_id, entry_title, entry_text, entry_created_on, entry_basename, mt_blog.blog_name AS blog_name,
                   mt_blog.blog_site_path AS blog_site_path, mt_category.category_label AS category_label,
                   mt_category.category_basename AS category_basename, COUNT(mt_asset.asset_url) AS contadorImagenes,
                   mt_asset.asset_url AS asset_url, mt_asset.asset_file_ext AS asset_file_ext
            FROM mt_entry, mt_placement, mt_category, mt_blog, mt_objectasset, mt_asset
            WHERE
                   mt_entry.entry_id = mt_placement.placement_entry_id AND
                   mt_blog.blog_id = mt_entry.entry_blog_id AND
                   mt_placement.placement_category_id = mt_category.category_id AND
                   mt_entry.entry_status = 2 AND
                   mt_entry.entry_id = mt_objectasset.objectasset_object_id AND
                   mt_objectasset.objectasset_asset_id = mt_asset.asset_id
            GROUP BY mt_entry.entry_id
            ORDER BY mt_entry.entry_created_on DESC
            LIMIT 0, 16";
    $i=0;
    $RESULT = mysql_query($SQL);

    while($DATA = mysql_fetch_array($RESULT))
    {

        $entry_id=$titulo=$DATA[entry_id];
        $creacionNoticia=new DateTime($DATA[entry_created_on]);
        $creacionNoticiaToExplode=date_format($creacionNoticia,"Y-m-d");
        $creacionNoticiaExploded=explode("-",$creacionNoticiaToExplode);
        $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
        $creacionNoticia=$creacionNoticiaExploded[2]." de ".$meses[$creacionNoticiaExploded[1]-1]." del ".$creacionNoticiaExploded[0];
        $basenameFinal=str_replace("_","-",$DATA[entry_basename]);
        $categoriaBasenameFinal=str_replace("_","-",$DATA[category_basename]);
        $link=$link="http://www.periodicoabc.mx/".$DATA[blog_site_path]."/".$categoriaBasenameFinal."/".$creacionNoticiaExploded[0]."/".$creacionNoticiaExploded[1]."/".$basenameFinal.".php";
        $asset_Url=substr($DATA[asset_url], 3);
        $categoriaNoticia=$DATA[category_label];
        $imagen="http://www.periodicoabc.mx/".$DATA[blog_site_path]."/".$asset_Url;
        $imagenesNum=$DATA[contadorImagenes];
        if($imagenesNum > 1){$galeriaIntegrada='<span class="ni-type nc-gallery"></span>';}else{$galeriaIntegrada='';}
        $titulo=$DATA[entry_title]; 
        $text=strip_tags($DATA[entry_text]);
        $text = preg_replace("/^\W*((\w[\w'-]*\b\W*){1,16}).*/ms", '\\1', $text);

        ?>

        { "id": 
        "<? echo $entry_id; ?>" 
        , "titulo": 
        "<? echo $titulo; ?>" 
        , "fecha": 
        "<? echo $creacionNoticia; ?>" 
        , "imagen": 
        "<? echo $imagen; ?>" 
        , "video": 
        "<? echo $link; ?>"}
    <?}?>
<?}?>

],
"pagina":
"<? echo "1"; ?>"
"seccion":
"<? echo "noticias"; ?>"
```

Comment: try `echo json_encode($DATA);`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

```
$data = array(
  'field' => 'value',
  'id' => $entry_id
);
$result = json_encode($data);
echo $result;

{"field":"value", "id":7}
```

Also I turn on my telepathy mode and prepare a query for you :)

```
SELECT e.entry_id, e.entry_title, e.entry_text, e.entry_created_on, e.entry_basename, 
    b.blog_name AS blog_name,
    b.blog_site_path AS blog_site_path, 
    c.category_label AS category_label,
    c.category_basename AS category_basename, 
    COUNT(a.asset_url) AS contadorImagenes,
    a.asset_url AS asset_url, 
    a.asset_file_ext AS asset_file_ext
FROM mt_entry e
INNER JOIN mt_placement p ON p.placement_entry_id = e.entry_id
INNER JOIN mt_category c  ON c.category_id = p.placement_category_id
INNER JOIN mt_blog b      ON b.blog_id = e.entry_blog_id
INNER JOIN mt_objectasset oa ON oa.objectasset_object_id = e.entry_id
INNER JOIN mt_asset a ON a.asset_id = oa.objectasset_asset_id
WHERE e.entry_id = 7
GROUP BY e.entry_id
ORDER BY e.entry_created_on DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

try it

Comment: OP, are you check it?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that your are trying to reinvent the wheel.
PHP comes with a perfect function called: "json_encode".

Just put your data in it (array, object ...) and it will transform it for you.
In your case, do the following:

```
$data = array(
    'id'     => $id,
    'titulo' => $titulo,
    'fecha'  => $fecha

);
echo json_encode($data);
```